# Assigning value to a double array

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am unable to assign dynamic value to an array which is double. If i keep it static, I am able to do it. Help me out.

I have defined a array as double whose size could be dynamic. Then I calculated some value and want to assign that value to this double array.
I did..

```
double[] entropy_db_col;
```

But I am getting an error. array out of index.
If i calculate,  `(double)entropy_db - (double)a`, I am getting a static value. 
Even if I do `entropy_db_col[0] = (double)entropy_db - (double)a;`, then also I am getting the error? What should I do ?

Then I want to find the largest value from this array? Is this code right ?

```
 largest = Convert.ToInt32(entropy_db_col[0].ToString());
```

Please help me out.
It would be great.

I solved this, but now the problem I get is :

I get entropy_db_col[0] value, then..when I iterate and get entropy_db_col[1] value, the value of entropy_db_col[0] becomes 0. Similarly when I get entropy_db_col[2], the value of entropy_db_col[1] and entropy_db_col[0] becomes 0..what should i do ?

Comment: Given your comments in the answers, I suspect there's more code to the snippets you've shown above.  Is `i` being changed anywhere other than the `for` statement?  Is `entropy_db_col` referred to anywhere other than you have shown?  Are you creating a `entropy_db_col = new double[...]` every time in the loop?  Double-check.

Answer (score 3):

create memory with data.count

before it used

```
entropy_db_col=new double[data.count]
```

Comment: The problem I get is
I get entropy_db_col[0] value, then..when I iterate and get entropy_db_col[1] value, the value of entropy_db_col[0] becomes 0. Similarly when I get entropy_db_col[2], the value of entropy_db_col[1] and entropy_db_col[0] becomes 0..what should i do ?

Comment: debug and watch each iteration whether the value from your data is getting or not. watch this "(double)entropy_db - (double)a" value is it may be 0.

Answer (score 0):

#### Dynamic array

A `double[]` is not a dynamic array so much as an array of undefined size.  It must first be defined with a concrete size, such as `new double[data.Count]` before it can be used, but this causes its size to be fixed.

If you want an array that can change size at any time, use a `List<double>` instead from the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

...

List<double> entropy_db_col = new List<double>();

for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
{
    \\some calculation
    entropy_db_col.Add((double)entropy_db - (double)a);
}
```

#### Largest value

To find the largest value in .Net 3.5 or later, you can use:

```
using System.Linq;

...

double largest = entropy_db_col.Max();
```

Or if you're using an version of .Net older than 3.5, you can use:

```
double largest = entropy_db_col[0];
for (int j = 1; j < entropy_db_col.Length; j++)
{
    if (largest < entropy_db_col[j])
    {
        largest = entropy_db_col[j];
    }
}
```